# Data Distribution in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, function

Seemed like a normal thing until I started working on it and come to realize that it is more complicated than I thought, any pointers would be helpful, tried all the ranking functions and the percent functions.

We have 4 people in a game and each player has a certain amount of cards to begin with (Cardcount in table below), the two players with the highest number of cards would start playing(A and B start in table below) by throwing in a card until one or more players with the same number of cards as one of the players can join the game

```
Player | Cardcount | 1st Round | 2nd Round | 3rd Round
-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------
  A    |     8     |    7      |    6      |   5
  B    |     3     |    2      |    1      |   0
  C    |     2     |    2      |    1      |   0
  D    |     1     |    1      |    1      |   0


Player | Round | Cards remaining | Comments
-------+-------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------
  A    |    1  |     7           | Player A & B start - have the highest cards 
  B    |    1  |     2    
  A    |    2  |     6           | Player C joins - same number of cards as B  
  B    |    2  |     1    
  C    |    2  |     1    
  A    |    3  |     5           | Player D joins -same number of cards as B & C 
  B    |    3  |     0    
  C    |    3  |     0    
  D    |    3  |     0
```

This is what I would like as the output

```
Player | Round | Cards remaining
-------+-------+-----------------
  A    |   1   |     7    
  B    |   1   |     2    
  A    |   2   |     6    
  B    |   2   |     1    
  C    |   2   |     1    
  A    |   3   |     5    
  B    |   3   |     0    
  C    |   3   |     0    
  D    |   3   |     0
```

Any pointers using SQL functions would be helpful

I am trying to work out the query to predict the results. In the example above we have 4players and each player starts out with a certain number of cards A(8cards), B(3cards), C(2cards) D(1card). Also the number of players is not fixed and 4players above is just an example. The max number of players could be upto 20.

Comment: Please elaborate your problem. Are you trying to work out a query that would "play" this game or you need to "unpivot" results from your first table to looks like the 3rd table?

Comment: I am trying to work out the query to predict the results. In the example above we have 4players and each player starts out with a certain number of cards A(8cards), B(3cards), C(2cards) D(1card). Also the number of players is not fixed and 4players above is just an example. The max number of players could be upto 20

Comment: Please edit your question and add your clarification. As your question currently stands it is not clear.

Comment: Appreciate you pointing this out, I have added more text to my question. Hopefully it adds clarity now.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `apply` :

```
select t.player, tt.rounds, tt.rounds_val as CardsRemaining
from table t cross apply
     ( values (1, [1stRound]), (2, [2ndRound]), (3,  [3rdRound]) 
     ) tt(rounds, rounds_val)
order by rounds;
```

Comment: Thanks but that did not answer my question, I am struggling with picking the top two or more players and then decrementing them as they play. For instance player A starts with 8cards and by Round3 has 5cards.

Comment: @ModerateSQLr. . . Sorry, i didn't understand what you want to achieve with said example.

Comment: I have added some more clarity to the question - I am looking for a query to predict the results of the game